# console.log not showing up when called from a onclick callback [javascript]

Tags: javascript, events, console.log

Say I have a function like this:

```
var some_value = 0
function refresh(something)
{
    // Log our value
    console.log(some_value);

    // If this function was invoked by clicking our some_div created below, set some_value
    if(last.getAttribute("baby"))
    {
        some_value = 1;
    }

    // Create some div, give it a random attribute and add an onclick event
    some_div.setAttribute("baby");
    some_div.addEventListener("click", function(){refresh(this);}, false);

    // Log our some_value
    console.log(some_value);
}

// Call our function
refresh(null)
```

I would expect the console to look like this:

```
//refresh(null)
0
0

//clicked our some_div
0
1
```

Instead if looks like this:

```
//refresh(null)
0
0

//clicked our some_div
1
1
```

When is my some_value being set? This is making me crazy. I would really appreciate some help...

Comment: It looks, some_value  is a static variable.

Comment: where do you set `last`? Can you give a full code example?

Comment: You did it by yourself ... `some_value = 1;
`. Line 12 I think. Give a full code . Thats not clear enough to help

Answer (score 0):

`var some_value = 0` 
is executed just once as it is outside the function. After the first time you click on a div, some_value is set as 1.
You may have accidentally clicked that.
The next time you call the refresh() by clicking on a div, `some_value` has value 1 previously set. Then result will be

```
1
1
```

To get your desired result, make some_value a local variable inside refresh.

```
function refresh(something)
{
var some_value = 0 #value is initialised every time
.
.
.
}
```

Will give

```
0
1
```

Every time you click on a div.